# Books in spectral theory for finite dimensional spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request

I'm looking for beginner books of spectral theory for finite dimensional spaces. I've already heard about this subject, but I don't know where I can find it. What's the domain of this subject? (Linear algebra or functional analysis maybe?)

Another question: Spectral theory for finite dimensional spaces is just the spectral theorem? For example if I study the chapter 13 of this [book](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=RsPqtjiW50YC&printsec=frontcover&dq=schaum%20linear&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=BFlRU7WeA86L0QH61IHwDg&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=schaum%20linear&f=false), I know spectral theory for finite dimensional spaces?

I need help

Thanks

Comment: I'm not an expert but I don't think spectral theory for finite dimensional spaces extends to anything beyond the basics of eigenspaces and eigenvectors.

Comment: @EricO.Korman Spectral theory for finite dimensional spaces is just the spectral theorem? what is spectral theory for finite dimensional spaces exactly?

Comment: Not a book, but I hope useful: http://www.caam.rice.edu/~caam440/chapter1.pdf